# Please explain the difference between function($variable) and function()

Tags: php

I have two scripts:  the first script receives data via socket and does some stuff with it, the second script holds a function that gets called by the first script.  The function happens to make use of a variable created in the first script.

When calling the function from the first script, should I run it like this:

```
include 'secondscript.php';

//socket stuff, create $variable from input received

functionName()
```

Or like this:

```
include 'secondscript.php';

//socket stuff, create $variable from input received

functionName($variable)
```

I understand that one is a "global" declaration, but I'm having trouble understanding the significance of that.  And of course, I'm wondering if that is what's causing something not to work.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The first is parameterless and the second has a single parameter of `$variable` which is required.

Comment: Your question indicates a lack of fundamental understanding of PHP. I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're not using objects, all functions are "global" in scope, as long as they're included in the file that's calling them.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to read up on the basics of [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

```
functionName();
```

means you are requesting a function and passing no information to it.

```
functionName($someVar);
```

means you are sending it the information in the `$someVar` variable.

Comment: The basics of programming in general would be a better suggestion.

Comment: @Leigh Yeah, but it is a start. +1

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above:

The difference is simply the arguments passed. You can access variables through the `global` declaration within a function, but personally, I think it is a bad idea.

You will always want to know what arguments and types are being passed to and from a function. At least, if you don't want to define the arguments in the function definition, but still pass them as an argument to the function call, you can grab the passed args via something like `func_get_args()`:

```
// definition
function funca(Array $arr){
    // This tells funca to only allow Arrays as the arg type
}

// definition
function funb(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    // You dont define args, but can still pull them.
}
//call
funcb('a', 'b');
```